GetNameInfo win API does not resolve Chinese computer names on Windows 11?
I have a small lab based Active Directory environment with 3 devices.
They have the following OS installed.
DC running Windows Server 2022 hosting my AD server.
1.Endpoint running Windows 10 Pro (22H2 Build 19045.4780) [English US installation and default computer name is "Endpoint1"]
2.Endpoint running Windows 11 Pro (23H2 Build 22631.2861) [English US installation and default computer name is "Endpoint2"]
3.Endpoint running Windows 10 (22H2 Build 19045.4780) [Chinese-Traditional installed and dfault and computer name is "通用的用户"]
Both the devices are connected to the Active Directory server hosted on the DC.
I have confirmed that the reverse lookup zones are properly set in the DNS Manager on the DC and they  have proper entries .
I have a following test code that uses the GetNameInfoW windows API from winsock.
void func() {
    struct sockaddr_in sa;
    char str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    wchar_t host[NI_MAXHOST];

    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sa.sin_port = htons(80);

    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, "CORRECT_IP_HERE", &sa.sin_addr) <= 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error in inet_pton" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (GetNameInfoW((struct sockaddr*)&sa, sizeof(sa), host, NI_MAXHOST, NULL, 0, NI_NAMEREQD) == 0) {
        std::wcout << "hostname: " << host << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Error in getnameinfo: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
    }

    std::wstring wstr{ host };
    int size_needed = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, &wstr[0], (int)wstr.size(), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    std::string strTo(size_needed, 0);
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, &wstr[0], (int)wstr.size(), &strTo[0], size_needed, NULL, NULL);
    cout << strTo << endl;
}

int main()
{

    WSADATA wsaData;
    auto ret = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    func();
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}

I am trying to perform a reverse DNS lookup for XYZ reasons from each of the endpoints to see if the other endpoint is accessible and resolves to the correct name.
I am running the above code on both the endpoints, as well as a 3rd endpoint (completely for testing) and i am able to see the resolution result correctly for 1 but not for 2.
Outputs [Endpoint1.ITDR.local]:
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>reverse_dns
hostname: ΘÇÜτö¿τÜäτö¿µê╖.ITDR.local
Outputs [Endpoint2.ITDR.local]:
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>reverse_dns
hostname: Error in getnameinfo: 10014
In both the endpoints above I Expect the SAME output. because the DNS Server is the same entity for both the endpoints.
I tried adding multiple fake reverse lookups with different values for english and chinese characters, weirdly for windows 10 all of them returned the expected responses while for windows 11, the non-english reverselookups all failed, while the english ones passed.
This is not a language pack issue, because nslookup is able to get the expected outputs and i have the chinese-t language packs installed on all the 3 endpoints.
Is this a microsoft bug?? Or am I doing something wrong ??

It appears that your UTF-8 data held in the strTo variable is being output to a std::cout that is not set to the 65001 codepage for the console it is being sent to.

In other words: The issue is with the code attempting to asset correctness rather than with the code itself. Here's a simple solution: Keep the UTF-16 and output to std::wcout.

@IInspectable it shouldnt matter, first and foremost, the "nRes" value should be a success which does not seem to be the case, indicating the API itself is failing, I advise you to check msdn for return values of GetNameInfo.

@Eljay If that was the case, endpoint 1 (running win 10) should give the same result. Dumping those results into a txt file using ofstream for that matter gives the correct expected output on the endpoint 1 (Win 10) and the result is consistent on the multiple win 10 setups i tried.  output.txt contents on win10 : "通用的用户.ITDR.local"
But the API itself fails on the multiple win 11 setups I tried. So I cant expect the "host" buffer to contain the right values as I have also passed "NI_NAMEREQD" parameter

Perhaps Windows 11 finally adheres to the Internet standards and does not allow non-ASCII DNS names like any other non-Microsoft OS on the planet? But 10014 errror code is weird, it means an invalid address is involved somewhere.

I fidgeted with my DNS settings on the endpoint 2 and now I am getting error : 11001 (which also is non-sensical to me, as the dns server is the same for both the endpoints 1 and 2.)
Edit: If it finally adheres to the standards why does nslookup give me the correct DNS name with the correct chinese characters that I have configured on both win11 and win10
